# Is it possible to create a file that cannot be copied?

Tags: windows

To restrict the scope, let assume we are in Windows world only.

Also assume we don't want to play with permission policy.

Is it possible for us to create a file that cannot be copied?

Thank  you in advance.

Comment: Is this a philosophical question?  Or perhaps a legal one?

Comment: I don't know to which category this question belongs. :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. You can't create a file that a SYSADMIN can't copy. You could encrypt it, though.

Comment: As long as you have a running process which holds an exclusive lock on the file, the sysadmin has to at least jump through some hoops to be able to access the contents.

Comment: You could write a system-level driver that restricts read access to certain file paths - even to a sysadmin. Non-readible files aren't very useful though.

Comment: Encryption doesn't stop you copying the file.

Answer (score 18):

"Trying to make digital files uncopyable is like trying to make water not wet." ~ Bruce Schneier

Comment: I hear Bruce Schneier can make water not wet.

Comment: Chuck Norris can make water not wet by looking at it.

Comment: Freeze the water

Comment: More precious Trying to make digital files uncopyable is like trying to make water not wettable

Answer (score 11):

Well, how about creating a file that uses up **more than 50% of the total space** on that machine and that is not compressible?
For instance, let us assume that you want to save a boolean (true or false) in such a fashion.
Depending on its value, you could then write a bit stream of `one`s or `zero`es and encrypt said stream using some kind of encryption algorith, such as AES in CBC mode. This gives you the added advantage of error correction. Even in case of massive data corruption, you should be able to recover your boolean by checking whether `one`s or `zero`es are prevalent in the decrypted stream.
In that case you cannot copy it around (completely) on the machine...
Of course, any type of external memory that can be added to the system would pose a problem in this scenario. But the file would be already encrypted, so don't worry about it too much...

Comment: -1 Considering the size of HDD computers have today, i don't think writing a file several hundred GB large is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Don't think it is practical to encrypt say 250 GB to save a boolean or whatevever (assuming an HDD of 500 GB9. What do you do when the system has several disks / partitions?

Comment: There is such a thing as irony in this world and actually I am surprised that nobody made any comment in that direction yet. Obviously, the solution, that I am proposing is

 - utter crap
 - not reliable
 - inefficient
 - influenced by many factors outside of the program's scope, etc...
 - making me shudder

But given the question, I simply could not resist.
Sorry everyone... ;-)
PS: I thought that my pseudonym might bring some attention to the irony, but obviously it did not. :-(

Comment: What if your copy target is another PC with a much bigger disk?

Comment: @skizz
Quote: "Of course, any type of external memory that can be added to the system would pose a problem in this scenario."
The moment you connect another PC with a bigger disk to the one the file is on, what you got is basically: a form of external memory. I cannot envision a solution to that problem (not even an ugly hack).

Answer (score 4):

Any file that can be read can have its contents written to another location (such as another file, i.e. copied).

The only thing you can do is limit who/what can read the file.

Answer (score 2):

What is the motivation behind? If it is a read-only file, you can have it as embedded resources within your assembly.

Comment: Yes. It would be far better to understand the requirements that led to this question. Perhaps there's another way to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Nice try, RIAA.

But seriously, no you can not. It is always possible to copy, you can just make it it more difficult for people to make sense of the file or try to hide it using like encryption. Spotify does it.

If you really try hard thou, you cold make a root-kit for windows and use it to prevent windows from even knowing about the file and also prevent copies. The file will still be there and copy-able by other tools, or Linux accessing the ntfs.

Comment: "... you cold make a root-kit for windows and use it ...": If you are  not the owner of the computer you are *rootkiting*, that is completely illegal!

Comment: That doesn't make it legal. They paid twelve digit dollars. Are you going to spend that much yourself?    The court was clear: "Ity is *your* software, but that's not your computer". You cannot modify it's behavior without an explicit user permission.

Comment: So now we have a justice where the man with the most dollars gets justice and the one who doesnt gets none? Is that what you want? The man with the dollars decides whats right and whats wrong? Its my computer, my private property, I do as I please on it, Ill flip its bits like theres no tomorrow. EDIT: Oh youre talking of installing rootkits on other peoples computers. Yeah, dont do that. Dont be Sony. Keep ethical.

Comment: "So now we have a justice where the man with the most dollars..." - don't go off-topic. Justice is not just yes-no. Penalties are defined by laws (not courts: they just assign them) and laws are made by people chosen by citizens (at least in the legal system we are talking about). Agree or not is a matter of politics, not justice and not programming. And this is stack-overflow!

Answer (score 2):

If in a running process you open a file and hold an exclusive lock, then other processes cannot read the file until you close the handle or your process terminates. However, as admin you could forcibly remove the lock handle.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

You can, of course, use security settings to limit who can read the file. But if someone can read it, then they can copy it. Even if you found some operating system trick to disable "ordinary" copying, if someone can read the file, they can extract the contents, store it in memory, and then write it somewhere else.

You can encrypt the contents so it's only useful to your own program, that knows how to decrypt it.

That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

When using Windows 7 to copy some files from a hard drive, certain files popped up a message saying they could not be copied in their entirety; certain data would be omitted from the copy.  I suspect that had something to do with slack space at the end of the files, though I thought the message was curious.  I would have expected the copy operation to just ignore the slack space.

Comment: You can lock byte ranges in files using LockFileEx.

Comment: You're talking about copying NTFS alternate streams to a non-NTFS filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running old (OLD) versions of windows, there are certain characters you can put in the filename that make it invalid, not listed in folders, etc.  They were used a lot in the old pub ftp days of filesharing ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the old DOS days, you used to be able to flag disk sectors as bad and still read from them. This meant the OS ignored the sector in question but your application would know where to look and be able to get the data. Not sure this would work these days.

Another old MS-DOS trick was to put a space character in the middle of the filename (yes, spaces were valid characters for filenames). Since there was no method on the command line to escape a space, the file couldn't be copied using the DOS commands.

Comment: "Since there was no method on the command line to escape a space..." Not true. Just wrap the string into "", like `copy "my file.xtx" "ur file.txt"` Valid since DOS 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This answer is outside Windows so yeah

Dont know if its already been said but what about a file that is an inseperable part of the firmware so that it is always on AND running, perhaps it has firmware that generates a sequence that is required for the other .  AN incedental effect of its running is to prevent any 80% or more of its code from being replicated.  Lets say its on an entirely different board, protected by surge protectors, heavy em proof shielding and anything else required to make it completely unerasable.
If its possible to make a program that is ALWAYS on and running as long as the copying software is running then yes.

I have another way and this IS with windows. I will come to your house and give you a disk, i will then proceed to destroy every single computer you put the disk into.  This doesnt work on XP

Comment: Or what if you found the smallest unique string of data in that file (as compared to the rest of the contents) and made a program that searched continuously all new processes for that string and stops any file from being created with that string in it before it is finished.  Im not sure what kind of data this would be - straight binary? idk im an illustrator
You could make the program go a few characters more to compensate for new files with that string though there couldnt be new files.

Answer (score 0):

A more philosophical approach.
As stated it is not possible to restrict files from being copied.

But as the important parts of a file are not the file itself but its contents it might be possible to create an encrypted archive that does not need a password for decryption but instead uses information of its location (path) and environment (partition details, hardware info) to form the password needed for decryption.

This way the file might be copied but that would make it useless as it could only be decrypted if it is still at the original location / within the original hardware / software environment.

Food for thought.

Answer (score -2):

Well technically you could create and write to a write-only network share.